# Single page analytics tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to GOogle Analytics. I have a single page site. It has multiple tabs that are reflected in the URL. Main url is index.html and if you switch to a different tab the URL becomes index.html?FaqPage

Is there a way to setup Google Analytics to give analytics on all the tabs seperately? I tried

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/index.html');
```

But the analytics only seem to track index.html and not any of the ther URLs. 
Also tried the following (with proer tracking code) but doesnt seem to work:

```
    ga('create', 'UX-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
    ga('set', { page: '/index.html?FaqPage', title: 'Faq'}, { page: '/index.html?MemberPage', title: 'Member'});
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. One solution is to  send a virtual pageview whenever a tab is clicked:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/faqpage')
```

And do similarly for all your tabs. Here is some more info https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications.